# Residue of a trig function multiplied by a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

can somebody help me to find the residue for:

I tried to make two series centered at $(z - k\pi)$ for $\sin(z)$ and $1- \cos(2z)$ but I don't know what to do with the $(z+\pi)^2$....and obviously, i couldn't find the right answer.

> $\displaystyle\frac{\sin(z)(z+\pi)^2}{1 - \cos(2z)}$

I tried to make two series centered at $(z - k\pi)$ for $\sin(z)$ and $1- \cos(2z)$ but i don't know what to do with the $(z+\pi)^2$....and obviously, i couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: Buenos dias. En el mundo de hablantes ingleses, "seno" se llama "sine", y entonces es $\sin$ pero no es $\operatorname{sen}$.

Comment: Podria usar $1-\cos(2z)=2\sin^2(z)$, entonces volvera $\dfrac{(z+\pi)^2}{2\sin(z)}$.

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea, but what i have to do with (z + pi)^2?

Comment: Podria usar $\sin(z)=-\sin(z+\pi)$

Comment: I think this is a better idea, because then i can make a serie, and put in a serie the (z+pi)^2, tomorrow i'm gonna tried by this way, and then will tell you...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the trigonometric identities

$$\sin z=(-1)^k\sin(z-k\pi)\;,\;\;\cos2z=\cos(2(z-k\pi))$$

and also

$$(z+\pi)^2=(z-k\pi+\pi(1+k))^2=(z-k\pi)^2+2\pi(1+k)(z-k\pi)+\pi^2(1+k)^2$$

and thus, using also the well known power series expansions for sine and cosine:

$$\frac{\sin z}{1-\cos 2z}=\frac{(-1)^k\left((z-k\pi)-\frac{(z-k\pi)^3}6+\frac{(z-k\pi)^5}{120}-\ldots\right)}{1-\left(1-\frac{4(z-k\pi)^2}2+\frac{16(z-k\pi)^4}{24}-\ldots\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{(z-k\pi)^2}6+\frac{(z-k\pi)^4}{120}-\ldots\right)}{2(z-k\pi)\left(1-\frac{(z-k\pi)^3}{3}+\ldots\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^k}{2(z-k\pi)}\left(1-\frac{(z-k\pi)^2}6+\frac{(z-k\pi)^4}{120}-\ldots\right)\left(1+\frac{(z-k\pi)^3}{3}+\frac{(z-k\pi)^6}{9}+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^k}{2(z-k\pi)}\left(1-\frac16(z-k\pi)^2+\frac13(z-k\pi)^3+\ldots\right)$$

and from here we get

$$\frac{(z+\pi)^2\sin z}{1-\cos2z}=$$

$$=\left[(z-k\pi)^2+2\pi(1+k)(z-k\pi)+\pi^2(1+k)^2\right]\frac{(-1)^k}{2(z-k\pi)}\left(1-\frac16(z-k\pi)^2+\frac13(z-k\pi)^3+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac{(-1)^k}{2(z-k\pi)}\left(\pi^2(1+k)^2+2\pi(1+k)(z-k\pi)+\left[1-\frac{\pi^2(1+k)^2}6\right](z-k\pi)^2+\ldots\right)$$

and from here that the residue at $\;z=k\pi\;$ is

$$\frac{(-1)^k\pi^2(1+k)^2}2$$

Comment: I don't understand what you did on the 2nd step, why you obtained an (z-kpi)^3 inside the big one parentesis?must to be (z-kpi)^2, or not?

Comment: @johndinatale That comes from the well known power series (Maclaurin series, if you want) for sine: $$\sin z=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\ldots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ Now just substitute $\;z-k\pi\;$ to get a power series around $\;k\pi\;$ instead of around $\;z=0\;$ .

Comment: No, i mean the part when you wrote that 2(pi - kpi)(1 - ((z-kpi)^3)/3 +......

Comment: @johndinatale Sorry, I just can't see such a thing $\;2(\pi-k\pi)...$ . Please be more specific.

Comment: Yes, next to 2(pi - kpi) the parentesis has the serie, and why you have a cube, when you had to have a square.

Comment: @johndinatale There are several places where that factor appears. For example, in my fourth line *of calculations*, in the denominator: is what is left of $\;1-\cos2z\;$ after factoring out $\;2(z-k\pi)\;$ for that series...

Comment: Yes, i mean the fourth line, when you made the factoring, inside the parentesis inside must to be (1 - ((z - kpi)^2)/3 +......) and you put (1 - ((z - kpi)^3)/3 +......), or i'm wrong?

Comment: @johndinatale Nop. The outer$\;1\;$ vanishes with the inner one, and the first remaining summand is $\;\frac{4(z-k\pi)^2}2\;$ . Then observe that one factor $\;z-k\pi\;$ in the numerator and denominator gets cancelled, and then I factor out $\;2(z-k\pi)\;$ .

Comment: Yes, but i think the answer is inside the parentesis below, i must be raised to the second power, not the third power, look at the picture: https://s32.postimg.org/8uvmafxkl/Series_example.jpg

Comment: @johndinatale No. The whole squared term disappears and becomes $\;1\;$: once from cancelling with $\;z-k\pi\;$ from the numerator, and once from factoring out. The remaining term there is from $\;\frac{16(z-k\pi)^4}{24}\;$ , which becomes, after (1) the cancelling and (2) the factoring out, in $\;\frac{8(z-k\pi)^2}{24}=\frac{(z-k\pi)^2}3\;$